# Keep the user input in browser without any binding to Bean

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, oracle-adf

I do have a sensitive user input entered by user. When user submits the page, it will sent to second server (https) (to which sending this sensitive data is fine) through javascript form submit. After that server process some, it will be returned to main server(https) with that sensitive input.

Problem here is, I cant bind this input to beans deployed in my server (as my server is not compliance certified). So when second server posts the values back, it is getting lost as it is not bonded. It may be really bad situation, but this is what happens.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: switch to use `https`

Comment: Both are https servers only, but I am trying to fix this in dev env which is http, is there any way I can see the difference in local?

Comment: The question is really not very clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the value in session scoped variable.